# c# json, detect object or boolean

Tags: c#, json

I have big json data https://app.anytimecar.ru/data/v3.4/info/

in the sample:
"client":false

but if you login there, "client" will be an object.

How can i detect it while deserealizing?

Comment: What do you mean with "but if you login there"? Where? What? How do you deserialize?

Comment: For nonlogged users client should be `null` not `false`. Can you change this?

Comment: C# is a type safe language, which means that changing the type of a property is not supported.  Changing from a bool to an object is not a good idea.  Instead, you should consider just using `null` for non-logged-on stuff.

Comment: The client object will be a class and the same class must exist in both the client and server code.  So in the client the class will be serialize and then in the server the class will be de-serialized.

Comment: I can't change the server-side code.

Comment: Just set client in your class as "object", then after deserializing check if the type is boolean (theObject.client.GetType() == typeof(bool)).

Comment: If you're willing to use an ugly hack, you could just replace `"client":false` with `"client":null` before processing the file.

Answer (score -1):

Not best way, but it works

```
string str = response.Content.ToString().Replace("\"client\":false", "\"client\":null");
```

And the desirialization works fine.